# Typesafe ConfigFactory error with reserved characters

Tags: java, typesafe, hocon

Hi I am trying to load configuration from a String in Java as follows:

```
@Test
public void testIllegalCharacter(){
    String input = "prop=\\asd";
    Config conf = ConfigFactory.parseString(input);
}
```

The code above produces the following error:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: String: 1: Expecting a value but got wrong token: '\' (Reserved character '\' is not allowed outside quotes) (if you intended '\' (Reserved character '\' is not allowed outside quotes) to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes, or you may be able to rename the file .properties rather than .conf)
```

I understand I have an illegal character in my String. Although how do I find the full set of illegal characters?

If I (for example) convert this String into a `Properties` object and then parse it with `ConfigFactory.parseProperties` I can see the value `"\\asd"` in resolved as `"asd".` So there must be some some **sanitising** going on in the typesafe library, I wish I could call that sanitisation myself, but I cannot see how. Parsing to Properties is not a viable solution as the configuration could be composed by Objects or Lists too.

**Has anyone have any suggestion how to solve this issue?**

**Alternatively can someone point out all the reserved characters set?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the error message correctly, you should put quotes around you special characters, e.g. like this:

```
"prop=\"\\asd\"";
```

Not sure why you's want a property definition with a backslash a ('\a') in it, but I guess I don't need to know :-)

Comment: You are correct, but my question would be, how do I programmatically apply a strategy to avoid the problem? I thought of catching the Exception and then retry, but that'd be bad practice.

Comment: To clarify this input will not work. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the answer. I need to set the `ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setSyntax(ConfigSyntax.PROPERTIES)`

Which works for the test below:

```
@Test
    public void test(){
        String input = "prop=C:/MyDocuments/mydir";
        Config conf = ConfigFactory.parseString(input, ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setSyntax(ConfigSyntax.PROPERTIES));
        assertEquals("C:/MyDocuments/mydir", conf.getAnyRef("prop"));
    }
```

But will not work for the test with backslashes

```
@Test
    public void test(){
        String input = "prop=C:\\MyDocuments\\mydir";
        Config conf = ConfigFactory.parseString(input, ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setSyntax(ConfigSyntax.PROPERTIES));
        assertEquals("C:\\MyDocuments\\mydir", conf.getAnyRef("prop"));
    }
```

Which fails:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :C:\MyDocuments\mydir
Actual   :C:MyDocumentsmydir
```

So I am not sure this is the definitive answer...